# Azure container shared access signature expiring

Tags: azure-storage

I'm having trouble with Azure Blobs and Shared Access Signatures when they expire. I need to grant access to a blob for longer than 1 hour (1 year), so I'm using a named container policy, but unfortunately . Its expiring after 1 hr

```
SharedAccessPolicy sharedAccessPolicy = new SharedAccessPolicy();
    sharedAccessPolicy.Permissions = SharedAccessPermissions.Read;
    sharedAccessPolicy.SharedAccessStartTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
    //sharedAccessPolicy.SharedAccessExpiryTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddYear(1); No need to define expiry time here.

    BlobContainerPermissions blobContainerPermissions = new BlobContainerPermissions();
    blobContainerPermissions.SharedAccessPolicies.Add("default", sharedAccessPolicy);

    container.SetPermissions(blobContainerPermissions);

    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue....");
    Console.ReadLine();
    CloudBlob blob = container.GetBlobReference(path);

    string sas = blob.GetSharedAccessSignature(new SharedAccessPolicy()
    {
        SharedAccessExpiryTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(7),//add expiry date only when you're creating the signed URL
    }
        , "default");

    Console.WriteLine(blob.Uri.AbsoluteUri + sas);

    Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo(blob.Uri.AbsoluteUri + sas));

    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue....");
    Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Did you regenerate the shared key of your account after the SAS was generated? If so, all the SAS generated with that shared key will be revoked as well.

Comment: Even if i regenerate the sas url, its working for only one hour. Afterwards its showing 403 forbidden error in AzCopy. Could you provide your thoughts on this?

Comment: If possible, can you please genarate the SAS key thorugh Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer and check the error status:
 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vs-azure-tools-storage-manage-with-storage-explorer#generate-a-sas-connection-string-for-the-account-you-want-to-share

Comment: It seems your code is based on an old version of storage sdk, so I test with oldest version 1.6.0 and it works on my side in both browser and AzCopy. I also test with latest version 9.1.0 with necessary changes, also works. Could you provide more details like your sdk version or how do you use the toke in AzCopy?